# how to set high quality of jlabel text

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying write some mechanism to creating mems. After the image is painted with text, the text quality is very low. I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my following draw method:

```
   private BufferedImage generateImage(File file) throws IOException {

    Image image = ImageIO.read(file);
    final int imgWidth = image.getWidth(null);
    final int imgHeight = image.getHeight(null);
    int labelHeight = (imgHeight / 2);
    int labelWidth = (imgWidth - 25);
    int xMargin = ((imgWidth - labelWidth) / 2);
    int yMargin = (imgHeight - (labelHeight + 10));
    Font font = new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 42);
    String upperText = this.doggle.getUppertext().toUpperCase();
    String bottomText = this.doggle.getBottomtext().toUpperCase();

    ImagePanel background = new ImagePanel(image);
    background.setSize(imgWidth, imgHeight);

    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
    String absoluteDiskPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/resources/images/logo.png");
    BufferedImage imageLogo = ImageIO.read(new File(absoluteDiskPath));

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageLogo);
    JLabel imageLogoPanel = new JLabel ();
    imageLogoPanel.setIcon(icon);
    imageLogoPanel.setSize(imageLogo.getWidth(), imageLogo.getHeight());
    imageLogoPanel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);

    JLabel textUpper = new JLabel();
    textUpper.setText(upperText);
    textUpper.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    textUpper.setSize(labelWidth, labelHeight);
    textUpper.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(labelWidth, (imgHeight / 2)));
    textUpper.setFont(font);
    textUpper.setForeground(Color.decode("#" + this.doggle.getUppercolor()));


    JLabel textUpperShadow = new JLabel(upperText, JLabel.CENTER);
    textUpperShadow.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    textUpperShadow.setSize(labelWidth, labelHeight);
    textUpperShadow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(labelWidth, (imgHeight / 2)));
    textUpperShadow.setFont(font);
    textUpperShadow.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    JLabel textLower = new JLabel(bottomText, JLabel.CENTER);
    textLower.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    textLower.setSize(labelWidth, labelHeight);
    textLower.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(labelWidth, (imgHeight / 2)));
    textLower.setFont(font);
    textLower.setForeground(Color.decode("#" + this.doggle.getBottomcolor()));

    JLabel textLowerShadow = new JLabel(bottomText, JLabel.CENTER);
    textLowerShadow.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    textLowerShadow.setSize(labelWidth, labelHeight);
    textLowerShadow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(labelWidth, (imgHeight / 2)));
    textLowerShadow.setFont(font);
    textLowerShadow.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    background.add(textUpper);
    background.add(textUpperShadow);
    background.add(textLower);
    background.add(textLowerShadow);
    background.add(imageLogoPanel);

    textUpper.setLocation(xMargin, 5);
    textUpperShadow.setLocation((xMargin + 2), 7);
    textLower.setLocation(xMargin, yMargin - 16);
    textLowerShadow.setLocation((xMargin + 2), ((yMargin - 16) + 2));
    imageLogoPanel.setLocation((xMargin - 5), ((yMargin * 2) - 8));

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    background.printAll(g2d);
    g2d.dispose();

    return img;

}
```

And here is a some part of the image (The text at the top is the actual text and bottom text is what it should look like)

What can I do to improve the visual quality of my text? I Will be grateful for help.

[image]

Comment: can you please specify what you mean by "create mems"?

Comment: Part of this seems to be based on the JPEG encoding settings

Comment: I've been playing around with your code and I can't seem to replicate your results.  Either the image has been scaled and/or the JPEG encoding has down graded the image. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: also, no matter how much antialiasing you apply, scaling up a snapshot of your outputted text will still show alias. As if I took a screenshot of the bottom text in you picture (with no alias) and zoomed all the way in, i would be able to see each pixel clearly.  I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: If high quality text is required in an OS agnostic app., I highly recommend ditching `JLabel` for rendering the text,  It is better to use something like `Graphics2D.drawString(..)` after setting the rendering hints of the graphic object.